# Nested attributes attack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I made a website like ebay, on which users can sell their products. It has models as below:

1. `User` has many `Product`.
2. `Product` has many `Product_packing_type`. `Product_packing_type` is used to describe the types of packing which customers can buy. For example, customers can buy one liter packing of milk, or three liter packing of milk.
3. `Product` has columns like `name`, `description`, etc.

I use nested attributes to edit the products; in other words, users can edit `Product` and `Product_packing_type` at the same time.

When users update their products, the server checks whether the products belong to the user or not by the `user_id` in the product. But the server doesn't check whether the `product_packing_type_id` belongs to the products.

Is it possible that some bad user uses the `product_id` that belongs to himself but nested attribute `product_packing_type_id` that does not belong to the product to modify other product's packing?

`update` function:

```
@product.update(product_params)  

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description,   product_packing_types_attributes:[:id, :quantity, :size] )
end
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your Models.

Answer (score 0):

From [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) document:

> If the hash contains an id key that matches an already associated record, the matching record will be modified.

In your code, the `product_params` has permit the product_packing_type's id attribute, so it will update the product_packing_type content.

BTW, if you don't permit the nested id attribute, it will always create a new product_packing_type object(s) while update the product.